# How to use prepare statement for Use database in Mysql

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

```
set @switch_schema= concat('use ', v6_schema, ';');

select @switch_schema; 
PREPARE s3 from @switch_schema;
EXECUTE s3;
```

Prepare statement does not support 'Use'; is there a solution to this?
The workaround is the following but I am looking for a more robust solution

```
set @db := v6_schema;

drop temporary table if exists tempdb.activeUnits;
set @query = concat ('create temporary table tempdb.activeUnits
select *
from ',@db,'.activemodelunits_blue
where active_datetime = (Select max(active_datetime) from ',@db,'.ActiveModelUnits_blue) ';
PREPARE s3 from @query;
EXECUTE s3;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid since you can't run `USE` as a prepared statement, your options are limited.

### `USE` before you call this routine

You could call `USE` from your application before calling the procedure where you reference the table.

```
USE v6_schema;
CALL MyProcedure();
```

### `USE` inside a `CASE`

If you are writing this code in a stored procedure, you can use the [CASE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html).

```
BEGIN
  CASE v6_schema
  WHEN 'myschema1' THEN USE myschema1;
  WHEN 'myschema2' THEN USE myschema2;
  WHEN 'myschema3' THEN USE myschema3;
  ELSE USE mydefaultschema;
  END CASE;
END;
```

This means you're limited to the finite list of schemas for which you have coded. You can't make this adapt to any future schema name you think of in the future, without updating the code.

### Use qualified table names

This is the workaround you mentioned in your question. Concatenate the schema name with table names, every time you reference those tables in prepared queries.